# java Thread Order

Tags: java, multithreading

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
     Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("thread1"));
     Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("thread2"));
     Thread thread3 = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("thread3"));
     Thread thread4 = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("thread4"));
     Thread thread5 = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("thread5"));

     thread5.start();
     thread3.start();
     thread1.start();
     thread3.join();
     thread2.start();
     thread1.join();
     thread4.start();
     thread2.join();
     thread4.join();
     thread5.join();
  }
```

I think the result of this run will be random. However, 5, 3 and 1 always come first.

Result1

```
thread3
thread1
thread5
thread2
thread4
```

Result2

```
thread3
thread1
thread5
thread2
thread4
```

Result3

```
thread5
thread1
thread3
thread2
thread4
```

Always 5,1,3 are executed followed by 2,4.
Why does an order exist?

Comment: Your results show 315 twice, then 513 which already means some variance. Of course the order will depend on the machine, its architecture, and the current load (other running programs). With the same conditions, you can mostly expect the same, or very similar, results. Starting a thread is actually not cheap, and takes a fair amount of time, which is why you can see consistent-ish results. On my machine I see 513, 531, 351 most commonly.

Comment: You have a bunch of join statements in there.  From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join()), this means the current thread will wait until the referenced thread dies.  So `thread3.join()` makes the main thread wait until `thread3` has had its turn to print to the output stream, which delays the starting of threads 2 and 4.

Comment: i understood. thanks.